# How to auto run oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, sql-procedure

Is there any possibility to auto run procedure after a specific time/date?
For example I want to auto run this stored procedure after 2 days:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deleteresetlinks
AS BEGIN  
  DELETE FROM passwordresetlink WHERE date_created <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3;
END;
```

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a scheduler job along the lines of this:

```
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job
    ( job_name        => 'DELETE_RESET_LINKS'
    , job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
    , job_action      => 'begin deleteresetlinks; end;'
    , start_date      => trunc(sysdate) +2
    , repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; interval=2;'
    , enabled         => true );
end;
```

Query USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS to check the details, and USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG and USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS for the run history.